# How to get text from notepad using JNA sendMessage

Tags: jna

How can I get text from notepad using JNA?

I tried the following code:

```
    public final int WM_GETTEXT = 0x00D;
    public final int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x00A;
    ...

    byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
    WinDef.LRESULT res = User32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(hwnd, User32.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    User32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(hwnd, User32.WM_GETTEXT, res.intValue() + 1, windowText);

    Native.toString(windowText);
```

but Native.toString(windowText) returns "0"

Comment: Do you have an example of this that works in native code?  If the `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` query returns zero, then there's no text to be obtained.

Comment: It seems the value for WM_GETTEXTLENGTH is 0x000E according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632628(v=vs.85).aspx